# Elastic terms aggregation on buckets results

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm using terms aggregation with minimum document count.

I would like to run another terms aggregation on the documents related to the former one.

In other words I would like to run a terms aggregation only on documents that is part of groups that bigger than 10.

Anyway to do this with elastic?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you want is called [Sub Aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html).

From that page's documentation:

Bucketing aggregations can have sub-aggregations (bucketing or metric). The sub-aggregations will be computed for the buckets which their parent aggregation generates. There is no hard limit on the level/depth of nested aggregations (one can nest an aggregation under a "parent" aggregation, which is itself a sub-aggregation of another higher-level aggregation).

Comment: I'm looking for aggregation to aggregate over all documents than answer the previous terms aggregation

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer, what you want is a "sub aggregation"

Comment: This will give me tons of buckets.

Comment: I want to group all documents in the buckets and then run a terms aggregation, otherwise I will have to sum the results..